# PulseAudio equalizer stutter and high CPU usage when changing volume or backspacing in an SSH terminal

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, 18.04, equalizer

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and yesterday I installed pulseaudio-equalizer and everything went fine! 
Today though, the audio stutters everytime I change the volume or, weirdly enough, when I backspace to the end of a SSH terminal (when you backspaced all characters it makes a noise). This might be linked to the "noises" the system makes when performing both of those actions, maybe it induces some kind of equalizing loop or something that leads to really High CPU usage and stuttering (pulseaudio becomes the top CPU consumer if I keep the backspace key down in my SSH term).

My audio output is set to "FFT based equalizer on Audio interne Stéréo analogique", if I set it to "Audio interne" it of course works, but I don't get the equalizing.

Any ideas on that? It is not the end of the world, just a tad bit annoying :) Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pulseaudio-equalizer is supposed to be a dead project...If you use equalizer when browsing web use chromium/chrome and 'Audio-EQ' extension

Comment: Oh ok I didn't check that! I use it to EQ the spotify desktop client since the desktop client doesn't have the EQ built-in.. If anyone has a good way to have an EQ for my desktop/for spotify, I'm interested then!